# How to stop one columns width from shrinking and have the other column fill the remaining width

Tags: html, css

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='col-1'></div>
      <div class='col-2'></div>
    </div>
```

```
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.col-1{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-2{
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

How can I achieve the result of col-1 adjusting its width up until a certain point? (let's say its width will stop shrinking at 20 rem, and col-2's width will auto adjust to fill the remaining width of the container space available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start ditching `flex` in favor of `grid`, it's so much easier and more powerful as well:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(15rem, 1fr) 1fr;
}

.col-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col-1'></div>
  <div class='col-2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this is valid for my use case?   grid-template-columns: minmax(27rem, 40%) 60%;

Comment: You don't work with percentages in grid, you work with **fr**actions of the available space (`fr`). That would then be `minmax(27rem, 2fr) 3fr;`

Comment: both of those yield the same result though? works great either way

Comment: They work even better. Working with percentages will mean there is no room for your second column if 27rem exceeds 40%. 60% cannot be adjusted automatically (because percentages do not relate to *remaining space*, but to *total space*); 3fr can.

Answer (score 1):

you can use display: grid; instead of flex. then set grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr; and then set both col-1 and col-2 width to 100%. that if you change the grid-template-columns both col-1 and col-2 will adjust with it!

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work!

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.col-1{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-2{
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class='container'>
      <div class='col-1'></div>
      <div class='col-2'></div>
    </div>
```

by replacing width: 60% from .col-2 to width: calc(100% - 100px); using calc!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `display: flex` you should use the `flex` methods of defining the scaling (instead of `width`).

```css
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.col-1 {
    flex: 0 1 20rem;
    background-color: blue;
}

.col-2 {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='col-1'></div>
    <div class='col-2'></div>
</div>
```